# WriteFile String Byte Length causes crash

Tags: winapi, assembly, crash, masm, masm32

**Problem**

I have been trying all sorts of byte counts trying to get [**WriteFile**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to work. The problem is it immediately crashes after writing to the file. All the text is in the file but yet the *"A program has crashed, send to Microsoft??"* Error Dialog pops up.

When commenting out invoke WriteFile and everything below it, the program runs fine and does not crash. However when I just uncomment WriteFile and leave all the code below it commented out it again rears it's ugly head. The code is below and if anybody can see something that I missed it is much appreciated :-)

**Byte Lengths I have tried.**

I have tried byte lengths of 23, 24 (string length + null), 25 (Maybe I forgot a byte), and also just using SIZEOF WriteText and all of them failed :-(.

**Code**

```
.386 
.model flat,stdcall 
option casemap:none ; Case Sensitive

; Windows
include \masm32\include\windows.inc 

; Kernel32
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 

.data 
FilePath         db "C:\test.txt",0
WriteText        db "This is some test text."

.code 
start: 

; Edit a file

invoke CreateFile, addr FilePath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE or FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL
push eax ; save the file handle

; This works other than the crashing, any number less then 23
; and the file has some of the text clipped
; any larger and NUL is appended until the byte count is matched.
invoke WriteFile, eax, addr WriteText, 23, NULL, NULL

pop eax
push eax

invoke CloseHandle, eax

invoke ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation for the WriteFile function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx):

> lpNumberOfBytesWritten [out, optional]
>   [...]
>   This parameter can be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL.

You have both lpNumberOfBytesWritten and lpOverlapped as NULL. Pass `addr some_writable_variable` as lpNumberOfBytesWritten and it should work.

Comment: Doh! I read that as "lpNumberOfBytesWritten [out, optional] [...] This parameter can be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is NULL." (As in both have to be null thank you.